# R data.frame Aggregate data to calculate diversity ratio

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame of data of demographics in **R**

```
Name...Region...Gender

...A...........1.............F

...B...........2.............M

...C...........1.............F

...D...........1.............M

...E...........2.............M
```

I want to calculate gender ratio for every region. Output should look like:

```
Region ..........GenderRatio

....  1........................(0.67)

....  2........................(0.50)
```

This can be calculated using normal BODMAS usage. Is there any efficient way to calculate it in R?

Comment: Output does not match your input: Region 2 is 100% male in your example data.

Comment: Hello and welcome on SO. You might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to improve the way you ask questions. This simplifies things for the people willing to help you and might therefore also improve your life. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `dplyr` library in R for all sorts of datamanipulation. See [here](https://www.tidyverse.org/) to learn more about `dplyr` and other extremely useful R packages.

An example:

First I create some sample data. (I changed it a little bit to actually have a gender ratio that fits your output.)

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
                 region = c(1,2,1,1,2),
                 gender = c("F", "M", "F", "M", "F"))
```

Now we can calculate `gender_ratio` and summarise the data. The function `mutate` is used to create and calculate the new variable `gender_ratio`. The `group_by` and `summarise` functions to logically organise the data before calculation (in order it is calculated by `region`) and later to only output the summarised data.

```
library(dplyr)                 
df %>% group_by(region) %>% mutate(gender_ratio = sum(gender == "F")/length(gender)) %>% group_by(region, gender_ratio) %>% summarise()
```

Output is:

```
  region gender_ratio
   <dbl>        <dbl>
1      1        0.667
2      2        0.5
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @symbolrush. This worked.

Answer (score 0):

As a (base R) alternative, you can use `by` with `prop.table(table(...))` to return a `list` of fractions for both male/female

```
with(df, by(df, Region, function(x) prop.table(table(x$Gender))))
#Region: 1
#
#        F         M
#0.6666667 0.3333333
#------------------------------------------------------------
#Region: 2
#
#F M
#0 1
```

Or to return only the male fraction

```
with(df, by(df, Region, function(x) prop.table(table(x$Gender))[2]))
#Region: 1
#[1] 0.3333333
#------------------------------------------------------------
#Region: 2
#[1] 1
```

Or to store male fraction and region in a `data.frame` simply `stack` the above result:

```
setNames(
    stack(with(df, by(df, Region, function(x) prop.table(table(x$Gender))[2]))),
    c("GenderRatio", "Region"))
#  GenderRatio Region
#1   0.3333333      1
#2   1.0000000      2
```